# Calculating the inverse filter for the (exponential) sine sweep Method

Tags: audio, impulse-response

I am currently working on my Bachelor-Thesis about Real-Time convolution and Impulse Response Measurements. After reading different papers about the (exponential)sine sweep method I didn't find an answer on how to calculate the inverse filter for deconvolving the impulse response.

In the papers I read, it is described as the Time Reversal Mirror and after that some kind of scaling.

Could someone explain, how to calculate the inverse filter for a given sine sweep?
If you could add an example, or an algorithm it would be appreciated

Comment: there is a terminology issue here.  a *"sine sweep"* is a signal, not a filter (unless you mean that the sine sweep is an impulse response of a filter).  **filters** have an inverse filter, but not signals.

Comment: so the papers I read most notably A. Farina's "Simultaneous Measurement of Impulse Response and Distortion with a Swept-Sine Technique" he is talking about creating an inverse filter so that the input signal x(t) convolved with said inverse filter f(t) results in a delayed dirac's delta function. So that the Output signal y(t) convolved with f(t) results in the impulse response h(t)

Comment: i might call that a form of a *"matched filter"*.  it **is** a delayed inverse filter of a filter having a sine sweep as its impulse response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your Exponential Sweep Sine was generated using the formula:

$$x(t)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi f_1 T}{R}\left(e^{\frac{t R}{T}} -1\right) \right)$$

where:

$f_1, f_2$ - Initial and final frequency of the sweep

$T$ - Duration of the sweep

$R = \ln\left(\frac{f_2}{f_1} \right)$ - Sweep rate

Then the inverse filter is calculated by scaling the amplitude of time reversed $x(t)$ by:

$k = e^{\frac{tR}{T}}$

Which will result in an exponentially decaying sweep:

$f(t) = \frac{x_{inv}(t)}{k}$

---

Example in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dbfft(x, fs, win=None):
    N = len(x)  # Length of input sequence

    if win is None:
        win = np.ones(x.shape)
    if len(x) != len(win):
            raise ValueError('Signal and window must be of the same length')
    x = x * win

    # Calculate real FFT and frequency vector
    sp = np.fft.rfft(x)
    freq = np.arange((N / 2) + 1) / (float(N) / fs)

    # Scale the magnitude of FFT by window and factor of 2,
    # because we are using half of FFT spectrum.
    s_mag = np.abs(sp) * 2 / np.sum(win)

    # Convert to dBFS
    ref = s_mag.max()
    s_dbfs = 20 * np.log10(s_mag/ref)

    return freq, s_dbfs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sweep Parameters
    f1 = 10
    f2 = 100
    T = 3
    fs = 1000
    t = np.arange(0, T*fs)/fs
    R = np.log(f2/f1)

    # ESS generation
    x = np.sin((2*np.pi*f1*T/R)*(np.exp(t*R/T)-1))
    # Inverse filter
    k = np.exp(t*R/T)
    f = x[::-1]/k
    # Impulse response
    ir = sig.fftconvolve(x, f, mode='same')

    # Get spectra of all signals
    freq, Xdb = dbfft(x, fs)
    freq, Fdb = dbfft(f, fs)
    freq, IRdb = dbfft(ir, fs)

    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(t, x)
    plt.title('ESS')
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(t, f)
    plt.title('Inverse filter')
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(t, ir)
    plt.title('Impulse response')

    plt.figure()
    plt.grid()
    plt.semilogx(freq, Xdb, label='ESS')
    plt.semilogx(freq, Fdb, label='Inverse filter')
    plt.semilogx(freq, IRdb, label='IR')
    plt.title('Spectrum')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dBFS]')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
```

And output:
[image]

[image]

For Robert, here is the spectrum plot for case without amplitude modulation of the inverse filter:

[image]

---

Relevant literature:

> [Q. Meng - Impulse Response Measurement with Sine Sweeps and Amplitude
> Modulation
> Schemes](http://guillaume.perrin74.free.fr/ChalmersMT2012/Papers/Impulse%20Response/IEEE_2008_LSP_IR_SineSweep.pdf)
>
> [A. Novak - Nonlinear System Identification Using Exponential
> Swept-Sine
> Signal](http://www.ant-novak.com/publications/2010_ieee_novak.pdf)
>
> [K. Vetter - ExpoChirpToolbox - a Pure Data implementation of ESS
> impulse response
> measurement](https://www.uni-weimar.de/kunst-und-gestaltung/wiki/images/ExpoChirpToolbox-_a_Pd_implementation_of_ESS_impulse_response_measurement.pdf)

Comment: where does $f_2$ figure into the equations?  i might imagine that there is a relationship between $f_1$, $f_2$, $T$, and $R$, but what is it?

Comment: Should be T. Fixed now

Comment: Thank you, this was what I missed, where did you find that Equation for _k_?

Comment: i'm thinking that the general **Exponential Sweep Sine** might look like: $$ x(t) = A \, \sin \left( \int_0^t 2 \pi f_0 2^{Ru} \, du \right)  $$  where $f_0$ is the initial frequency and $R$ is the sweep rate in units of octaves per unit time.

Comment: I did took it from my thesis, but probably I found it in Farina's work originally. I will check it once I get home. However if you look at the problem, you want to scale your amplitude by the scaled instantaneous frequency of your sweep.

Comment: Actually there is a lot of stuff laying around if you Google it. [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.uvic.ca/~timperry/ELEC499SurroundSoundImpulseResponse/Elec499-SurroundSoundIR-PreREVA.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjihab9qrvUAhUBOsAKHXJpBakQFgggMAE&usg=AFQjCNFxP99B3UudxlT5lSrN72117uqFSQ&sig2=jiMJ1NnIPzT_nrhTtxA31A) is an example.

Comment: @jojek, why would the OP *"want to scale* [their] *amplitude by the scaled instantaneous frequency of* [their] *sweep"*?  i thought the whole point of the exponential sweep (as an alternative to the linear-frequency sweep which has a lot of theoretical mathematical support; like it's a form of the Gaussian function) was that there is an equal amount of energy per octave in the exponential sweep.  with a constant amplitude $A$, you get that equal energy per octave and you can push that constant amplitude closer to the rails and have a decent *"crest factor"*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Short answer being: otherwise you will get a skewed frequency response after convolving the recording with unscaled time-reversed sweep.

Comment: it's *skewed* in a deterministic manner.  you know exactly how it is *skewed*.  you can compensate for the *skewing* in the frequency response.  but the point of driving an acoustic system with a broadbanded test signal is to get a good representation of frequency response and to have as high S/N ratio as possible without clipping or going significantly non-linear.  this is why low **crest factor** is salient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60405/discussion-between-jojek-and-robert-bristow-johnson).

Comment: well, you have the diamond, but i think that this is all technically relevant.

Comment: after reading the source you gave in the chat, I am still not sure about the equation for _k_ because the paper says that:
$$m(t) = \frac{2 \pi f_1}{\omega(t)}$$ with $$\omega(t) = \frac{K}{L}e^{\frac{t}{L}}$$ $$K=\frac{T 2 \pi f_1}{\ln(\frac{f_2}{f_1})}, L=\frac{T}{\ln(\frac{f_2}{f_1})}$$ is there something I overlooked?

Comment: Right, then it actually simplifies to $k=e^{\frac{tR}{T}}$, and $2\pi f_1$ is unnecessary.

Comment: shouldn't it be $$k=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{tR}{T}}}$$ I tried Implementing that in matlab an the decay was way too fast. I generated a sweep from 22Hz to 32000Hz in the span of 6 seconds. So $$F_1=22, f_2=32000, T=6$$ so putting that into the equation for _k_ it would result in $$k=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{tln(\frac{32000}{22})}{6}}} = \frac{1}{e^{1.2137t}}$$ so I used that on the time reverted sweep and after the 3rd sample the value was so low, that matlab couldn't display it anymore

Comment: Please continue any discussion in chat. I would appreciate if you move your comments there.

Comment: With your example code I found my mistake. I used the sample number for _t_ but you need to use the time in _s_. Thank you again for your patience

Comment: Excellent explanation! Very useful. Good guidelines to understanding Meng's paper

Answer (score -1):

@jojek answer is very good.

Long history short, the inverse ESS should be the ESS time reversed with amplitude scaling so after convolving with the ESS the frequency is constant in the [f1 f2] range.
In other words the closest to a diraq impulse.

The matlab code would be (approximately):

invSweep(n) = sweep(N-1-n) .* (f2/f1)^(-n/(N-1))

invSweep(n) = flip(sweep) .* (f2/f1)^(-n/(N-1))

N being the duration in samples of the ESS (sweep)

Perhaps there's some error in the style N instead of N-1.