# How to use deconvolution technique to find out impulse response?

Tags: impulse-response, speech-processing, deconvolution

I have been working to find out room for impulse response. I am using Logarithmic sweep sine wave as input say $x(n)$ and my recorded signal is $y(n)$. I know the room impulse response is theoretically as:
$$x(n) * h(n) = y(n)$$ where $*$ is convolution function.

I have read a research paper where it was pointed out that using the deconvolution technique we can get the room impulse response. I tried using `scipy.signal.deconvolve`. [Here you can view the documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html)

Now if I perform this process, I am not getting impulse response as per my expectations.
I think it may work as:
$${\tt deconvolve}((x(n)*h(n)),x(n)) = h(n)$$  where $x(n) * h(n) = y(n)$.

If theoretically, I am correct then why am I not getting the required result? Am I making any mistake? I am posting the files and also the code with a plot.

### Wav files

1. [$x(n)$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GSOho085d9A4eJ7DftxI-KXgS2XjBPFK/view?usp=sharing)
2. [$y(n)$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1km0rA278O_FlGQvYW8bZCqB1cmkj_Rqb/view?usp=sharing)

### Output Graph

[image]

Comment: Khubaivb, the first link (for $x(n)$) doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Hi. This is not how sweep-sine IR measurement should be done. There's no need to deconvolve the sweep from the recording. All you need is to create the inverse filter (which is time-reversed and amplitude modulated version of the original sweep) and convolve it with the recording. Here's how exactly: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41700/8202.

Comment: @PeterK. Apology for the inconvenience, I have updated the link.

Comment: @jojek That's great. It means that I just need to create a mirror image of my sweep signal and then perform convolution of this mirror and amplitude modulated signal with my recording and I'll get the room impulse response? Right?

Comment: That’s correct. Keep in mind that the inverse filter is closely tied to the playback sweep. You might have to regenerate it with a known parameters.

Comment: Okay. Just want to know one thing more. Will it work in real-time? If I implement this on an android device in real-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jojek [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/calculating-the-inverse-filter-for-the-exponential-sine-sweep-method/41700#41700)  helped me in attaining the impulse response.I tried the technique but there was some internal issue that my audio being played i.e ESS was noisy. I changed the player in python and it worked flawless.
Also what @hilmar pointed out initially, our data was noisy and due to issue in data, our result was faulty.
Thank you both guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your signals are not suitable for deconvolution. Did you listen to them ?

1. x(t) is a speech sample recorded in a reverberant space, so it already includes the room impulse response
2. y(t) is the same reverberant sample but with added noise (babble)

Both x and y include the same room impulse response (I think), so you can't possibly extract it through deconvolution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this thing Hilmar. I listened to them again and probably this is one of the ignored problems on our data. I'll retest with the jojek's technique.