# convert the Sweep signal into impulse response

Tags: matlab, sweep

Does someone know, how to convert the Sweep signal into Impulse response

I am testing that comparing software and hardware compressor with sweep signal

I generated a sweep signal from REW software and then correct the output value sweep signal from the compressor.

But i lost the way that how to convert the sweep signal into impulse response with matlab

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Relevant answer:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41700/8202

However, few notes on your approach. First of all, measuring IR of compressor is not a good idea - it's a Time Variant system due to attack / release. You will get different results depending on length of sweep, it's level, etc.
Second of all, RoomEqWizard has a measurement sweep option, where in signal generator you create a recording, play it back through whatever chain you want and capture the output. Then, in the menu, you can go into "Import" and select measurement sweep. After that, provide both original and recording.

Comment: I'm 99.44% sure that when you say "IR" you mean "impulse response".  Could you please _edit your question_ to replace the abbreviation with the true phrase -- if I were absolutely sure you meant "impulse response" I would do it myself.

Comment: Hi Heimishyun. Welcome to DSP.SE. Please don't repost questions in the future but instead improve your original post by addressing the questions in the comments. This one can now be closed since OP reposted here: [how to convert the Sweep signal into Impulse response](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/how-to-convert-the-sweep-signal-into-impulse-response)

Comment: I have sine sweep , now I am trying to convert sine sweep into impulse response with matlab